# Running a script in zsh without ./ before works in /usr/local/bin but not ~/bin

Tags: macos, zsh

I'm fairly new to this and encountered a problem
I tried to run simple script in the terminal on macOS and read through other threads about where to put scripts and add them to the `PATH`.

So now I have scripts in `~/bin` which I'd like to run but it always says `Command not found` even though `~/bin` is in my `PATH`.
When I put the same script into `/usr/local/bin` the autocompletion works and I can run them just with `scriptname`
When I'm in `~/bin` I can also run the script by `./scriptname` but I would rather just type `scriptname` and would prefer a solution without introducing `aliases` for every script.
What am I missing?

**SOLVED**

putting `$HOME/bin` into the `PATH` rather than `~/bin` solves the problem.

Comment: What's the output of `which scriptname`? Be careful with auto-completion. If you move or copy an executable, zsh autocompletion will only recognize it after you run `rehash`.

Comment: it just says `scriptname not found` ...

Comment: but the `~/bin` is definitely in the `PATH` that's why I don't understand this...

Comment: realized that when I don't put `~/bin` but the full path as in `/Users/myname/bin` into my `PATH` it works as expected...is that wanted behavior?

Comment: There is no directory named `~`. Hence you can't put it into the path. If you use it properly in your **shell**, it will be substituted by the shell for your home directory. You did not show, how you added this directory to your PATH, but likely you did it in a wrong way.